# Having troubles with Cloudscraper, no output

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping, python-multithreading

Have been attempting to scrape an xml sitemap for all urls and adding them to a list

I'm righting my first python app using tkinter, one of the features of this app is to scrape info from a site, for basics i want to first scrape every link from an xml sitemap and then store them in a temporary list untill they get placed visually later.

```
import tkinter as tk
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from lxml import etree
from tkinter import *
import cloudscraper
```

```
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

def scrape_urls(url, scraper, output_list, keyword):

    print('3')
    def scrape_link(url, scraper, output_list, tag_name):
        try:
            print('Scraping:', url, scraper, output_list, tag_name)
            response = scraper.get(url)
            root = etree.fromstring(response.content)
            for element in root.iter(tag_name):
                print('Link:', element.text)
                output_list.append(element.text)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error scraping', url, ':', e)


    def scrape_list(url, scraper, output_list, tag_name):
        response = scraper.get(url)
        root = etree.fromstring(response.content)
        for element in root.iter(tag_name):
            output_list.append(element.text)
        

    if keyword == 'list':
        # Static list of words to match against URL
        static_list = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
        if isinstance(url, list):
            for link in url:
                with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=24) as executor:
                    executor.submit(scrape_list, url, scraper, static_list)

    elif keyword == 'loc':
        print('4')
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=24) as executor:
            if isinstance(url, list):
                for link in url:
                    executor.submit(scrape_link, link, scraper, output_list, 'loc')
            else:
                print('5')
                executor.submit(scrape_link, url, scraper, output_list, 'loc')
    else:
        messagebox = tk.messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Invalid keyword")
```

#example
#scrape_urls('https://www.sitemaps.org/sitemap.xml', scraper, temp_list1, 'loc')

```
pip install lxml
pip install cloudscraper
pip install tkinter
```

Python 3.12.1

I was able to scrape it successfully a few times but then decided to redo and optomise using things like
cloudscraper instead of requests
tkinter instead of PyQt
lxml-entree instead of beautifulsoup for xml
and added threading to do all 10thousand ish links in 24 intervals

now no matter what i try i cant get the scraping working, even directly forcing the arguments
does anyone know what i'm doing wrong or have suggestions

Please I'm not remaking or trying something else completly off topic I'm doing this as a learning experience and to have fun, the website im scraping does not have any rules against scraping and is not provided but here is an example.

https://www.sitemaps.org/sitemap.xml

Thank you in advance!